# Spacing apart mtext in a plot

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have a question regarding the `mtext` function.
I have done a PRC analysis and have obtained species weights (bk).
Now, I would like to make a plot including the species weights and the species names, but making sure my species names are **readable**.

my species weight data:

```
subsetspeciesweights <- c(-1.3452, -0.7742, -1.3027, -1.0156 ,-0.5008,  0.5071,  0.9389, -1.2601, -1.6869, -2.3473, -0.7346,-0.6425, -0.8218, -1.9169, -2.8776, -0.8199 ,-1.8433, -1.9338, -0.5464,  0.7367)
```

my species names data:

```
subsetspeciesnames <- c("D.lo n","S.ve t","C. s ph","A.na n","A.qu a ","A.sp ec","Cycl","L.lu n","L.pa t","Tric ho","Aspl","A.fi s","Am","T.si m","Br.s p","Dis","M.ve n","Noto" ,"Proa","C.sp e")
```

I make a plot as follows:

```
ylimmin <- round(min(subsetspeciesweights)-2)
ylimmax <- round(max(subsetspeciesweights)+2)
plot(x = 1000, y = 1000, xlim = c(0, 5), ylim=c(ylimmin, ylimmax), xaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = expression("b"[k]))
```

Then, I add the ticks to my y-axis at the values of my weights:

```
axis(side=2, at=c(subsetspeciesweights),labels=FALSE,lwd.ticks=2)
```

Now, i would like to add my species weights. I have tried the following:

```
mtext(side = 2, text = subsetspeciesnames, at = c(subsetspeciesweights), las = 1, line = -3, cex = 0.6)
```

[image]

However, because my weights are close to each other, a consequence is that my species names overlap, and that they are not readable.

I was wondering whether there is another function (or an additional parameter to the `mtext` function) that I can use to make sure the species names are spaced apart so that they are **readable**.

In addition, because the species names will no longer be directly opposite to the species weight on the y-axis, is there a way to connect the species name to the species weight value by **drawing a line** between both, so the reader can still determine what the species weight of a particular species is?

Thanks for your time,
Tina

Comment: If you don't have to stick to `base::plot`, you may consider [ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).